# Yii2 deep joinwith

Tags: join, yii2

I am using yii2. I have four tables:

1. `posts`: contains post by users (`post_id`, `user_id`, `post`)
2. `mapPostClasses`: map posts with their classes (`map_id`, `post_id`, `class_id`)
3. `mapUsersClasses`: maps users with classes (`map_id`, `user_id`, `class_id`)
4. `Users`: user details table (`user_id`, `name`, etc..)

Now i want a join query for `Posts table` to find all posts `WHOSE CLASS_ID IS SAME AS THE GIVEN USER'S CLASS_ID`.

Sample SQL that i am currently using is

```
Select p.* FROM posts p ,mapUsersClass muc, mapPostsClass mpc
muc.user_id = $user_id
AND mpc.class_id = muc.class_id
AND p.post_id = mpc.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActiveQuery`:

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select('*')
->from('posts p')
->join('join','mapPostsClass mpc','p.post_id = mpc.post_id')
->join('join','mapUsersClass muc','mpc.class_id = muc.class_id')
->where('muc.user_id = '.$user_id.'')
->all();
```

Comment: but i want results to be returned as active records of Post AR Class. else i am still getting the results as array